# To Remove prefill textbox in chrome(in ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, autofill

I Have textbox for username and password in login and inside application also to register users. But the problem is Textbox and password is coming already filled with some values which i have used in past while log in. It is not changing even after using diffferent credentials. I have seen many post for work around like to put `"autocomplete"=Off` `disable` but nothing works for me.
Please help
Chrome version is : 48.0.2564.116 m [Attach is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRv2h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autocomplete = "off"`is ignored by some browsers so you need a different approach.

Answer in the link below helped me with the same issue

[disable autofill chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/15917221#15917221)